# Wouldn't and wouldn't have

Tags: would

1 My dog wouldn't let me catch him yesterday

2 My dog wouldn't have let me catch him yesterday

What is the difference between them. I intend to say that yesterday I tried to catch it but I didn't make it. I know that we use would have for things we intended to do but didn't or things that were meant to be done before something or by the times. I think that we use would with repated action but I intend to say that it happened only once.

Comment: (1) expresses the intended meaning. (2) requires something more - _he wouldn't have let me catch him if I hadn't had a pocketful of dog treats_, for example, meaning that because you _did_ have them you were able to catch him.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think that once I remove yesterday 1 may be ambiguous. It may mean that it didn't let me catch itself in the past or it's just me wondering what may happen in the future when I want to catch it. Am I right?

Comment: Talking about the usual situation, it's _My dog won't let me catch him._  Without _yesterday_, (1) could mean 'at some unspecified time in the past' or 'if I ever tried'.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

1 My dog wouldn't let me catch him yesterday=
I tried to catch him but couldn't do so.

2 My dog wouldn't have let me catch him yesterday=
I didn't try to catch him because he would not allow it. Past tense of will.

Present tense:
My dog never lets me catch him.

Use of will:
Use of will to express what my dog is not willing to do: let me catch him, for example.
My dog will never let me catch him.

Comment: Thank you Lambie. What about used to? Do I need longer period of time to use this phrase?

Comment: My dog never used to let me catch him. But now he does (let me catch him). It is not about a longer period of time. It's about a habit here. Also, My dog will let me catch him. I am sure of that now.

Comment: Yes. You can't normally use _used to_ for something yesterday, or probably even last week. But there is no objective definition for how long ago it has to be before you would use it. BUt it definitely refers to something done repeatedly or habitually.

Comment: Thank you, guys.

Comment: One more question. Someone asks me about something. I answer a I would' ve known that but now I don't or b  I would know that but know I don't. Is there a difference?

Comment: I would've known that in the past but now I don't. I forgot it. The other is no. I *should* know that but know I don't. Think about it. :)

Comment: 1 I should know it but I don't vs 2 I should have known it but I don't. 1 states that I should know something now in the presence and 2 refers to the past it says that I was supposed to know something in the past.  Am I right? Does it work the same way with would and woul have?

Comment: should know is present tense. should have known is past. No, will/would are different. Just read my answer. It's a problem using cellphones on this site. It's better with a computer...

Comment: Ok. Could you elaborate why it is  not ok to use would?

Comment: will/would shows that will is would **in the past**. And would can also a conditional.  Just make the examples in the answer declarative and add an if clause: My dog would let me catch him if I gave him a treat.

Comment: @Lambie, so do you think, the sentence in number 2 has also another meaning, which Kate Bunting explained, "requiring something more". I mean, considering both your points as native speakers, I think the number 2 does have 2 meanings, doesn't it?

Comment: @yunus Good question. We're both right. She adds something more by making the whole thing a conditional.  Mine has yesterday at the end, as the past tense of will. You and I are talking. You say: Oh wow, he won't let you catch him. And I respond: He wouldn't let me catch him yesterday, either. These are not different meanings; they are different uses.